# PHP scope issue within while loop

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, scope

Trying to teach myself php and I am struggling with what I think is a scoping issue?

I have a query, while loop, if/else and a function.

I would like to echo the results of the function `get_patronapi_data($id)` within my while loop.

My code so far is as follows (stripped for legibility);

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT... ...");  //QUERY here ...

if( $stmt->num_rows > 0 )
{
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
       if (SomethingIsTrue){
             echo get_patronapi_data($id);
            }
       else {
             echo $somethingElse;
            }  
    }//end while
}//end if

define("APISERVER", "http://mydomain:4500");

function get_patronapi_data($id) {
    $apiurl = "APISERVER" . "/PATRONAPI/$id/dump";//line 135
    $api_contents = get_api_contents($apiurl);
    $api_array_lines = explode("\n", $api_contents);
        foreach($api_array_lines as $line){ 
            if(strpos($line, "EXP DATE") !== false){ 
                $data = explode("=", $line); 
                return $data[1]; 
            }//end if
        }//end foreach
 }//end function

function get_api_contents($apiurl) {
    $api_contents = file_get_contents($apiurl);//line 154
    $api_contents = trim(strip_tags($api_contents));
    return $api_contents;
}//end function

echo get_patronapi_data($id); // this works and echoes $data on screen
```

Whenever I `echo get_patronapi_data($id);` outside of the functions I successfully see the data on screen. However when I `echo get_patronapi_data($id);` within the loop I receive the following errors;

> Notice: Use of undefined constant APISERVER - assumed 'APISERVER' in
>   C:\xampp...search_1.php on line 135
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(APISERVER/PATRONAPI/3047468/dump): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp...search_1.php
>   on line 154

I'm sure I am doing something very silly however any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you don't define `$data` anywhere in the `while` loop. (maybe you meant `while ($data = $stmt->fetch())`?)

Comment: as per your edit; there you go. You didn't define `APISERVER`. It's treated as a constant http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php. Either you define it as a constant, or wrap it in quotes.

Comment: @Fred he says he got it to work by calling the function outside of the while-loop though.

Comment: @Glubus variable scope then. which is what I was thinking earlier.

Comment: `APISERVER` is probably a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). You must [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) it before it is used. Otherwise PHP displays the notice you mentioned and converts it into a string. The scope of the constants is the entire script. On the runtime, a constant is available starting with the moment when the `define()` statement is executed.

Comment: @Fred I guess you're right, not sure how he got that function going outside of the while-loop then though

Comment: `define("APISERVER",     "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx");` as your very first line.

Comment: @johnny_s wrapping `APISERVER` in quotes doesn't help. PHP already told you in the notice it used `'APISERVER'` instead and the warning tells the path generated this way is not valid ("no such file or directory").

Comment: then now you need to remove the quotes from `$apiurl = "APISERVER"` since it's treated as a string literal.

Comment: then do this `function get_patronapi_data($conn, $id) {` and apply the same when calling the function. and possibly for `function get_api_contents($apiurl) {` also. or make it available within the global scope.

Comment: also check for folder/file permissions. and make sure that tmp folder isn't full.

Comment: Almost there. I've ready all the comments carefully (adding `$conn` helped!) and it looks like if I put `echo get_patronapi_data($conn,$id);` anywhere on the page it will work, APART from inside the if (SomethingIsTrue) else {}. I can live with this though. I really do appreciate your patience!

Comment: you're welcome. so, if I submitted my comments as an answer, would that basically solve this for you?

Comment: It sure would - thanks! Not sure why I was downvoted though :S - I must have confused people.

Comment: @johnny_s I have posted my answer below. However, the rest will have to be done on your side in order to fix that `if (SomethingIsTrue) else {}` issue.

Comment: Not a problem, thanks again. I've just cleaned up some of my comments here to tidy things up!

Comment: @johnny_s You're welcome and I have gotten rid of some comments also. *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting some of my comments to an answer.

You need to remove the quotes from:

```
$apiurl = "APISERVER" . "/PATRONAPI/$id/dump";
          ^         ^ <<< remove those
```

since that's treated as a string literal, rather than a constant.

It is declared in:

```
define("APISERVER", "http://mydomain:4500");
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Then your connection is out of scope and should be used inside your function(s).

I.e.:

```
function get_patronapi_data($conn, $id)
```

and do that for all your functions requiring a connection for them.

You will need to make sure that all folders/files have proper permissions to be written to.

Answer (score 2):

The missing link is the statement:

```
$data = get_patronapi_data($id);
```

you should put before `echo $data;`.

It calls the function `get_patronapi_data()` passing the value of variable `$id` as argument and stores the values the function [return](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)s in the variable `$data`.

The variable `$data` you [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is not the same as the one used by the function. They use the same name but they are different (I hope you **don't** use the keyword `global` in the function).

Read more about functions in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).

The updated (fragment of) code looks like:

```
    if (SomethingIsTrue) {
        $data = get_patronapi_data($id);
        echo $data;
    } else {
        echo $somethingElse;
    }
```

If you don't do further processing on the value returned by the function, you can, as well, remove the temporary variable `$data` from the code fragment above and just use:

```
    if (SomethingIsTrue) {
        echo get_patronapi_data($id);
    } else {
        echo $somethingElse;
    }
```

Comment: it's a variable scope issue then; which was what I was thinking also earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to print the data from the get_patronapi_data() every iteration in the while loop, you need to actually call the method instead of using $data. Right now you're trying to print something called $data, though you never set a value to it. The $data you return in the function cannot be used outside of that function, so it does not exist in the while loop.

What you could do in your while loop is $data = get_patronapi_data();, and then echo $data. However, you can just echo get_patronapi_data(); first.

If you only want to call your function once, you need to set a variable before you start your while loop (i.e. $variable = get_patronapi_data()), and then use that variable in your while loop (i.e. echo $variable);

Comment: Thanks for this - that makes a lot more sens to me now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  What happens if you just put

echo get_patronapi_data($id);

in the loop instead of

echo $data;

?  As written, you're not calling the function in the loop.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that please?

Comment: Well when you say "Whenever I echo get_patronapi_data($id); I successfully see the data on screen" what do you mean exactly?  Does the data returned by the function change with every iteration of the loop or is it constant?  If constant, then above the while loop just add a line "$data = get_patronapi_data($id);"  if it changes, you could just put that line above your in-loop echo.

Comment: This does not provide an answer, just another question and on top of that it's not formatted proper as well